# InfoPath Form Auto generate Name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath

Here is the requirement:

Anonymous Users need to enter some info into InfoPath on line form.

They should not see the Save as and the file name prompted after they hit the Save.

Should I find a way to auto generate name for InfoPath / write some code for this?

I also need to create a workflow when a new form is created [send an email].

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto generate Name:
I use a datetime and remove the fomatting. It works to a second it depends on on you application. It works for most cases for us.

Here us a link to find an auto number:
http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/autonumber-infopath-form-submitted-sharepoint-library.htm

As for the work flow, you could just have an "alert me" on the document libray. Simple Is always best.

CJ

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a form using a data connection and rules. When you create your data connection in the designer, you will get a dialog that will give you a chance to specify the name of the file. You can use values from the fields in the form, built-in functions for date/times, math calculations, etc...
That approach is described here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/infopath/archive/2007/03/26/submitting-to-a-sharepoint-list.aspx